# How to Get the Data from Navigation Property of OData Service

Tags: odata, sapui5

We are creating the Master Details UI5 app. I am calling the OData service and able to display the data from an entity set in Master list. On detail section, we are creating a form and I want to display the data which is coming from Navigation entity set. As I came to know that we can not call navigation entity set in a single call, how can it be done?

```
<EntityType Name="Product" sap:content-version="1">
    <Key>
        <PropertyRef Name="ProductID"/>
    </Key>
    <Property Name="ProductID" Type="Edm.String" Nullable="false" MaxLength="10" sap:label="Product ID" sap:updatable="false"/>
    <Property Name="TypeCode" Type="Edm.String" Nullable="false" MaxLength="2" sap:label="Type Code"/>
    <NavigationProperty Name="ToSalesOrderLineItems" Relationship="GWSAMPLE_BASIC.Assoc_Product_SalesOrderLineItems" FromRole="FromRole_Assoc_Product_SalesOrderLineItems" ToRole="ToRole_Assoc_Product_SalesOrderLineItems"/>
    <NavigationProperty Name="ToSupplier" Relationship="GWSAMPLE_BASIC.Assoc_BusinessPartner_Products" FromRole="ToRole_Assoc_BusinessPartner_Products" ToRole="FromRole_Assoc_BusinessPartner_Products"/>
</EntityType>
```

I would like to show the data of `ToSupplier`.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to make use of navigation property?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52483541/how-to-make-use-of-navigation-property)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Well, you can get it in a single request actually.

Lets say that your "BusinessPartner" entity has a name field and you want to display something like this:

```xml
<Panel>
   <Text id="txtProductID" text="Product ID Comes Here"/>
   <Text id="txtSupplierName" text="Supplier BP Name Comes Here"/>
</Panel>
```

What you can do, is to use regular binding syntax (with relative bindings), as it is usually done in details views:

```xml
<Panel>
   <Text id="txtProductID" text="{ProductID}"/>
   <Text id="txtSupplierName" text="{ToSupplier/Name}"/>
</Panel>
```

If you would try this directly, you would not get anything in the "Supplier Name" text control. This is because, by default you are not requesting the `ToSupplier` navigation to be **expanded** (check out chapter 4.6 from the [OData Spec](http://www.odata.org/documentation/odata-version-2-0/uri-conventions/)).

You should do this where you are calling [bindElement](https://openui5.hana.ondemand.com/#docs/api/symbols/sap.ui.core.Element.html#bindElement) on the detail view (in the default template, this is done in a method called `_bindView` of the detail controller). The expand can be passed as a parameter to [the binding](https://openui5.hana.ondemand.com/#docs/api/symbols/sap.ui.model.odata.v2.ODataContextBinding.html) itself like so:

```js
oView.bindElement({
    path: sMyPathToAProduct,
    parameters: {
        expand: "ToSupplier"
    }
});
```

You can expand as many navigations as you like and as deep as you like (you can pass the navigations as a comma separated list in that parameter). The only constraint here is that your backend should support expands / might have some limitations on how deep you can go with expands.

Comment: Another question: What If I would like to get the values from ToSupplier in my Master's Controller and would like to print that in console?

Comment: You have two options: either you expand the `ToSupplier` navigation for all the items of the master list (you can do this directly in the XML, when you are binding the items, e.g. `items="{path: '/ProductSet', parameters: {expand: 'ToSupplier'}}"`). Then you can obtain the data itself from the binding context of the items. Or you can do a programmatic read when you need the data (look at [ODataModel#read](https://openui5.hana.ondemand.com/#docs/api/symbols/sap.ui.model.odata.v2.ODataModel.html#read)).